# how do I structure a jquery .after statement with a table and multiple classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a table in jQuery using .after. Here is my code

```
$( nearestRow ).after( "<table class=" + 'table responsive bordered' + "></table>" );
```

The problem that I am having is that the dom is not generating the table correctly.

The dom is generating it without spaces. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what spaces you're expecting, but I'm guessing you're trying to set `table`, `responsive` and `bordered` classes on the table. However, since they're not quoted in your string, which is actually:

```
<table class=table responsive bordered></table>
```

You just have `class=table`, and `responsive` and `bordered` attributes.  You want to say:

```
$( nearestRow ).after( "<table class='table responsive bordered'></table>" );
```

To set those three classes.